# Selecting multiple documents in folder via powershell

Tags: powershell

first of all i am a complete newby when it comes to PowerShell.
I kind of inherited a project from a colleague and want to improve it.

In a PowerShell script I want to select **multiple** documents via System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog which shall later be opened.
Building on the work of my colleague i wrote this.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
       

$defaultFolder='Pfad'            

Function Get-FileName($defaultFolder)
{   
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.windows.forms”) |
 Out-Null

 $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
 $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $defaultFolder
 $OpenFileDialog.filter = “All files (*.*)| *.*”
 $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
 $OpenFileDialog.filename
} end function Get-FileName
 
    

 $OpenFileDialogr.Description = "Bitte zu archivierenden Ordner wählen"
          
 $OpenFileDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = $false            
            
# Dialog anzeigen            
$res =  $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()            
if($res -eq 'Cancel'){
    return
}
```

I do get the error that the property description was not found.

Can somebody help me with this?

BR

Comment: You have a typo: `$OpenFileDialogr` (notice the `r` at the end)

Answer (score 1):

As Mathias already commented, you have a typo in your code, but also you are using curly 'smart-quotes' (`“` and `”`), which can make code do weird things..

By doing `$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null` you are effectively throwing the returned value ('OK' or 'Cancel') away. The code below uses that to make sure we return nothing upon Cancel.

I would change the function to

```
function Get-FileName {  
    [CmdletBinding()]  
    Param (   
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]  
        [string]$WindowTitle = 'Open File',

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$InitialDirectory,  

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*",

        [switch]$AllowMultiSelect
    ) 
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    $openFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $openFileDialog.Title  = $WindowTitle
    $openFileDialog.Filter = $Filter
    $openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = $true
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($InitialDirectory)) { $openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory }
    if ($AllowMultiSelect) { $openFileDialog.MultiSelect = $true }

    if ($openFileDialog.ShowDialog().ToString() -eq 'OK') {
        if ($AllowMultiSelect) { 
            $selected = @($openFileDialog.Filenames)
        } 
        else { 
            $selected = $openFileDialog.Filename
        }
    }
    # clean-up
    $openFileDialog.Dispose()

    return $selected
}
```

and then call it like:

```
$defaultFolder='Pfad'
Get-FileName -WindowTitle "Bitte zu archivierenden Dateien wählen" -InitialDirectory $defaultFolder -AllowMultiSelect
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

When running your code i do get the error:
Missing "}" in the instruction block.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace

Comment: @Peter I think you didn't copy **all** of the functions code and forgot the final closing `}`. Please check that. For me it works as intended

Comment: @Peter Nice to hear! Being new to the platform you may not know this, but it's customary to accept the answer that solved your problem by clicking the checkmark icon to the left. This helps other people with a similar question to find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Creating new object + adding assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FilePicker = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog

#modify properties
$FilePicker.InitialDirectory = 'C:\' #setting initial directory
$FilePicker.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt" #filter files in the directory
$FilePicker.Multiselect = $true #allowing multiselect !! make sure to put this before the ShowDialog() property
$result = $FilePicker.ShowDialog() # show dialog 
$fileDirectory = $FilePicker.FileNames #make sure to use FileNames not Filename as your property

foreach($files in $fileDirectory)
    {  
        "You picked " + $files
        "-------"
        "Text in " + $files 
        Get-Content -Path $files
    }
```